# Simple select not returning all rows and sp_who returns no blocks

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, nolock

I'm running a simple select on a table with a small amount of rows, and it's running for forever. I found that it returns fine if I run:

```
SELECT TOP 23 * FROM MyTable ORDER BY 1
```

However, it hangs forever if I run:

```
SELECT TOP 24 * FROM MyTable ORDER BY 1
```

If I run `sp_who` or `sp_who2`, there is no one blocking. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The performance of the two queries should be essentially the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The problem was an open transaction inserting a 24th row. Running with `nolock` returned the row in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run with `nolock` on (ignoring uncommitted transactions), you should be able to select all rows:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
```

There's a transaction somewhere that has not been committed or rolled back (I'm not sure why it doesn't show up in `sp_who`). You can run the following to force all transactions to rollback, and then selecting should work fine without `nolock`:

```
USE master
ALTER DATABASE DbName SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
ALTER DATABASE DbName SET MULTI_USER
```